# Not receiving entire MySQL error message using die(mysql_error)

Tags: php, mysql

I try to do this:

```
    <?php
  if(isset($_POST['update']) && isset($_GET['topic_id']))
  {
      $title=$_POST['title'];
      $tag_h1=$_POST['tag_h1'];
      $tag_h2=$_POST['tag_h2'];
      $tag_metadata=$_POST['tag_metadata'];
      $content=$_POST['content'];
      $topic_id=$_GET['topic_id'];


     mysql_query("
     UPDATE topic
     SET tag_h1=$tag_h1,tag_h2=$tag_h2,tag_metadata=$tag_metadata,content=$content,title=$title
     WHERE topic_id=$topic_id
     ") or die(mysql_error);

     echo "$title<br/>";
     echo "$tag_h1<br/>";
     echo "$tag_h2<br/>";
     echo "$tag_metadata<br/>";
     echo "$content<br/>";
  }

?>
```

But i get error 100 in chrome, and nothing appears in firefox

Comment: What is the actual error message coming with it?

Comment: it comes with nothing.. php emits nothing..that what makes the programming in php so difficult

Comment: Your code is also begging for injection attack. You should escape your input before passing it to your database!

Comment: Why are you trying to do both a POST and a GET? When you submit a form, it's one or the other.

Comment: i dont care it is teh admin page. Cillosis in my particular case, it is necessary

Comment: @cillosis Not strictly so. You can do `<form action='handler.php?id=123' method='post'>` and both the standard `$_POST` and `$_GET['id']` will be populated.

Comment: hmmm... that is irrelevant to the question

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Irrelevant to the question? You have not asked a question. I see a statement and some code. The rest is left up to the clairvoyance of SO to extrapolate...

Answer (score 4):

Your query is failing because none of the input values are enclosed by quotes:

```
mysql_query("
 UPDATE topic
 /* Enclose all variables in single quotes (unless they are integer values) */
 SET tag_h1='$tag_h1',tag_h2='$tag_h2',tag_metadata='$tag_metadata',content='$content',title='$title'
 WHERE topic_id='$topic_id'
 ") or die(mysql_error());
//-------------------^^^^
// () needed here.
```

Note 1: `mysql_error()` is a function that must be called with `()`. That's why you saw no error printed.

Note 2 , this script is wide open to SQL injection attacks.  Filter all `$_POST` values with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

```
  $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
  $tag_h1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag_h1']);
  $tag_h2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag_h2']);
  $tag_metadata = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag_metadata']);
  $content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
  $topic_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['topic_id']);
```

Comment: no that is okay mike, it is an admin page.. not a users page

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd No it is never okay, even if used for internal purposes. Even though  you may not worry about malicious tampering, the query will still break if an input value contains a `'` character for example. You MUST escape them.

Comment: or die(mysql_error) ..there is the error... should be or die(mysql_error()).. too bad i have no error checker for typos. lol.. okay I will try to

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd That is what prevents you from seeing the error with the query. Quote the input variables so the query succeed.s